# MySQL query get product have multiple color and order by number of color product have

Tags: mysql

I have one table product(id, name) have n-n relationship with table color(id, name), and 1 table product_color(product_id, color_id). How can i query all product can have multiple color (example i want query product can have color red, green, blue) and order them by number of color coincident( product have 3 color red, green, blue will be first, then product with 2 color and 1 color last)

Comment: I try this:

SELECT p.id, p.name, c.name
FROM product AS p
INNER JOIN product_color AS pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
INNER JOIN color AS c ON c.id = pc.color_id
WHERE c.name = 'red' or c.name = 'blue' or c.name = 'green'.

It's only get product can have one of 3 color or can have all of 3 and i dont know how to order by number of color having in product coincident with condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use  a select form the joined  table  and count the number of distinct color

```
  select prod_name, count(distinct color_name)
  from ( 

        select 
              a.id  prod_id
            , a.name prod_name
            , b.id color_id
            , b.name color_name
        from product a
        inner join product_color c on a.id  = c.product_id
        inner join color b on b.id = c.color_id
        where b.name in ('red', 'green', 'blue')

  ) t 
  group by prod_name
  order by count(distinct color_name) desc
```